# PDF File Size in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, mobile

I'm new to developing and have just completed my first Xcode app.

However, the app contains certain PDF files within an image view controller. These files are quite large - at about 17.6mb I'm worried they will take me over the 100mb download limit that some cell phone carrier operate in the UK.

However, I heard that Xcode converts pdf files to pngs when compiling. Does this mean I shouldn't really worry about the bloated pdfs or should I reduce the pdfs file size and compromise on quality?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

Xcode does not convert PDF files. Why do you need to embed such large PDFs in an iOS app? You may want to consider using some kind of tiling strategy. Read the documentation for `CATiledLayer` for some ideas. What you may be able to do is convert your PDF to PNGs yourself, but at several sizes, and then use the tiled layer to manage which one you put in your view. `CATiledLayer` will interpolate between these for you at any intermediate sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode converts PDF to bitmap at build time, if the PDF is used as an image resource. This may or may not reduce the output size -- it all depends on what's in the PDF.